# Selenium: Alert fails to execute before driver closes

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, webdriver, browser-automation

I have a code like this:

```
public class classTest {
    WebDriver webDriver;
    WebDriverWait wait;

    ExpectedCondition<Boolean> pageLoadCondition = new
            ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
                public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                    return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
                            .executeScript("return document.readyState")
                            .equals("complete");
                }
            };

    @BeforeEach
    public void init() {
        webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
        wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 10);
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void quit() {
        webDriver.quit();
    }

    @Test
    public void Test1() {
            ...
    }

    @Nested
    class classTest2 {
        @BeforeEach
        public void create() {
            ...
        }

        @AfterEach
        public void closeAlert() {
            webDriver.get("https://...");

            ...

            Alert alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
            webDriver.switchTo().alert().accept();
        }

        @Test
        public void Test2() {
            ...
        }
   ...
```

When `Test2()` completes, the `closeAlert()` method is executed.

An alert appears on the page, but `accept()` fires 50% of the time. My guess is that it does not have time to fire, because the `quit()` method is immediately executed, which closes the browser.

I've tried`wait.until(pageLoadCondition);` after alert, but that doesn't help.

How do I wait for the alert confirmation to complete?

Answer (score 0):

You could wait for an actual WebElement to be displayed/etc... on the web page.

If you don't have a specific element, you could use a couple miliseconds of `Thread.sleep`.

Might not be the ideal solution, but as long as you only need to wait, and nothing else, it should do the trick.